# WooCommerce product permalink not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-404, permalinks, wiki

I am using WooCommerce plugin. I have added the product permalink(Settings ->Permalinks) to Custom Base(/shop/%product_cat%) it works fine. But if I updated it to (/%product_cat%) products page working fine but website pages and posts are linking to 404 page. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you are trying to have %postname% for the wp pages and posts and %product_cat%/product name for the woo commerce product single pages.

And in case of product permalinks 'Custom Base' will be working if we set a base for it. You can see the below message next to that

"Enter a custom base to use. A base must be set or WordPress will use default instead."

So yo have to set a base, which by default is 'shop'. Without the base no other permalink structure will be accepted here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert into your theme functions.php this code
2. After go to setting -> Permalink Settings -> Product permalinks block -> field Custom base & insert here: **/%product_cat%/**

Code:

```
add_action( "update_option_woocommerce_permalinks", "apply_product_cat", 10, 3 );

function apply_product_cat( $old_val, $new_val, $option_name ) {
    if ($option_name == "woocommerce_permalinks") {
        $new_val['product_base'] = "/%product_cat%/";
        update_option( "woocommerce_permalinks", $new_val );
    }
}
```

[Original answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014935/removing-shop-from-woocommerce-urls)