# Removing /shop/ from WooCommerce URLs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I have a WooCommerce installation where product URLs are produced as such:

```
domain.com/shop/product-category/product-name/
```

Due to SEO and current site structure, I would like to change it to:

```
domain.com/product-category/product-name/
```

I know how to remove shop from the breadcrumb using the woocommerce_get_breadcrumb filter, but I am unsure how to proceed for the URLs themselves.

All I've found on Stack Overflow are people recommending to install a plugin called Premmerce. This plugin has a premium version and constantly hassles you to upgrade: [Removing /product-category/ and /shop/ from URL in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752543/removing-product-category-and-shop-from-url-in-woocommerce)

I would like to do this programmatically from my own plugin or just functions.php

Comment: See here - https://working-out.info/woocommerce-remove-product-product-category-or-shop-from-links-text

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that this solution causes issues with URLs; it swabs the entire thing out, and it also causes problems with WPML. Overall it breaks URLs. It seems my problem mostly comes from WooCommerce not enabling /%product_cat%/ on its own in custom settings. To have things work natively, it would probably be better to go that route: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65017217/extending-a-woocommerce-admin-class/65018370

In addition, it seems that the way Premmerce gets around this is by updating the woocommerce_permalinks option on its own.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce forces /product/ on you if you try only inputting /%product_cat%/ in the permalinks panel through class-wc-admin-permalink-settings.php. The wc permalinks is an option called "woocommerce_permalinks". Since I only want to have /%product_cat%/, I can just force it even though it's not the most elegant solution:

```
add_action( "update_option_woocommerce_permalinks", "apply_product_cat", 10, 3 );

function apply_product_cat( $old_val, $new_val, $option_name ) {
    if ($option_name == "woocommerce_permalinks") {
        $new_val['product_base'] = "/%product_cat%/";
        update_option( "woocommerce_permalinks", $new_val );
    }
}
```

What Premmerce does is effectively offer you another admin panel, where they just save to this option on their own.